# Add stage in kanban view (Odoo 13)

Tags: python, odoo

How add a stage "new" in OCA module wchich field :

```
stage_id = fields.Many2one(
        'mgmtsystem.action.stage',
        'Stage',
        track_visibility='onchange',
        index=True,
        copy=False,
        default=lambda self: self._default_stage(),
        group_expand='_stage_groups',
    )
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you are extending it with your own module, then it goes something like that

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <!-- It mofifies the original starting stage to be second and to be nonstarting -->
    <record id="mgmtsystem_action.stage_draft" model="mgmtsystem.action.stage">
        <field name="sequence">1</field>
        <field name="is_starting" eval="False" />
    </record>
    
    <record id="stage_new" model="mgmtsystem.action.stage">
        <field name="name">New</field>
        <field name="sequence">0</field>
        <field name="is_starting" eval="True" />
        <field name="is_ending" eval="False" />
    </record>


</odoo>
```

if you can edit the original module then edit mgmtsystem_action_stage.xml file:

https://github.com/OCA/management-system/blob/13.0/mgmtsystem_action/data/mgmtsystem_action_stage.xml

Comment: Can I use : attrs="{'invisible': [('stage_id', 'in', ['draft','in progress'])]}" to make some fields invisible ?

Comment: No , you can not use like this, Try attrs="{'invisible': [('stage_id.name', 'in', ['draft','in progress'])]}" this insted.

Comment: @Saumil gauswami  ,when trying this : attrs="{'invisible': [('stage_id.name', 'in', ['draft','in progress'])]}" , a js error is displayed ...

Comment: Now you can do is with xml id of this stages. use this:-  attrs="{'invisible': [('stage_id', 'in', [%(mgmtsystem_action.stage_draft)d, %(mgmtsystem_action.stage_open)d])]}".......It will definately work.